# 2D Interactive Javascript Grid

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to gather data using a 2D XY grid where each grid axis represents a different quantity. Basically I want to record the point a user clicks within the grid.

Is it possible to embed something like this within a webpage?  I can find plenty of charts for plotting XY data, but none that allow interaction and to gather data from the user.

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

David

Comment: It should be quite easy: Attach a `onclick` event handler to your canvas, then calculate the grid coordinate from the mouse position (basically divided by grid block size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript allows you to register [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for any HTML object in your document (not just since HTML5). A click event handler will receive a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) which includes the coordinates where the click happened. You can then use these coordinates as user input and record them in whatever way you need.

```
 // find your element by its ID propery
 var element = document.getElementById('id_of_your_grid');     
 // add an event listener to it
 element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
      // your code ...
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So could the document element in your code be an image of a 2D grid?  It's been a while since I've done any JS and HTML.